# knitr to pdf, attach file

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, rstudio

**Task:**
I am generating a pdf document with knitr and latex in RStudio.
The code generates in addition also a dataframe which I can export as a .xls/xlsx-file with the xlsx package.

**Problem:**
For easier distribution, I want to attach/embed the .xls/.xlsx-file to the .pdf-file.
My preference is to achieve this during the knitr run in RStudio?

**Question:**
Is this possible?
Any other suggestion to achieve the embedding?

Comment: run a wrapper script to put the pdf and xls(x) file (and the original Rnw file) into a zip file?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible with `knitr`. However, Didier Stevens has a [set of tools](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) that will let you do the embedding. It's probably simpler to do what [Ben](http://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) suggested, though. Another option is to make the xls[x] file available via http[s] and provide a download link in the document.

Comment: If you're willing to do some LaTeX wrangling, [dvipdfmx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/attach-files-to-pdf-with-dvipdfmx) might work for you (and references this [paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94cho.pdf) [PDF] by the author of `dvipdfmx`.

Comment: See [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052/5764) with specific reference to the [`embedfile` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile), which allows you to attach a file to a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914686/werner) for your comment, that lead me to this solution.

I used following approach for the same problem to produce pdf output from R Markdown.

1. Check if [`embedfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) Latex package is installed: `tinytex::check_installed("embedfile")`
2. If not, install it: `tinytex::tlmgr_install("embedfile")`
3. Include this additional package dependency in your R Markdown, as described in the [official document to add latex dependency](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html)

   ```
   output: 
     pdf_document:
       extra_dependencies: ["embedfile"]
   ```
4. Then add a raw latex script somewhere in your R Markdown document as described in [the official document to include raw latex](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html). An example R Markdown chunk below:

   ````
   ```{=latex}
   \embedfile[desc={My file is for}]{"myfile.xlsx"} 
   ```
   ````
5. You may also include that file from anywhere inyour computer by specifying the full path. In that case you can use `filespec` option to specify the filename appropriately inside the generated PDF. An example R Markdown chunk below:

   ````
   ```{=latex}
   \embedfile[desc={My file is for}, filespec=myfile.xlsx]{"\path\to\myfile.xlsx"} 
   ```
   ````
6. If your filename has some special character like `_`, then you can use `stringmethod=escape` option to escape it and show correct filename appropriately inside the generated PDF. An example R Markdown chunk below:

   ````
   ```{=latex}
   \embedfile[desc={My file is for}, stringmethod=escape,
    filespec=my_file.xlsx]{"\path\to\my_file.xlsx"} 
   ```
   ````