# R markdown: can I insert a pdf to the r markdown file as an image?

Tags: r

I am trying to insert a pdf image into an r markdown file. I know it is possible to insert jpg or png images. I was just wondering if it is also possible to insert a pdf image. Thanks very much!

Comment: What is a "pdf image"? Do you mean "insert a link to a PDF file", or "show an image that approximates how the PDF will render in a PDF viewer"?

Comment: A function I am using only generates pdf output. It produces an image for DNA sequence alignment. Is it possible to use the function directly in an r markdown code chunk? or I can generate the pdf first and somehow put it in the markdown document like we did for png image files. Hope it is clear now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly, you want a programmatic way to extract an image from a PDF and show that image in the report. I don't know of any R package that will accomplish this. You should be able to do it with a `system2` call using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s `convert` command, or perhaps the `pdfimages` command.

Comment: I landed up here to attach a file inside PDF output generated by R Markdown (not HTML output). In case it helps anybody in the future, here is a solution to that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725736/9689416

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry, I found that there is a similar post before:
[Add pdf file in Rmarkdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073041/add-pdf-file-in-rmarkdown-file)

Basically, I can use something like below works well for the html output:
`<img src="myFirstAlignment2.pdf" alt="some text"  width="4200" height="4200">`

And something like below works well for the pdf output:
(1)possible solution

`\begin{center} <br>
\includegraphics[width=8in]{myFirstAlignment2.pdf} <br>
\end{center}`

(2)possible solution
`![Alt](myFirstAlignment2.pdf)`

The `myFirstAlignment2.pdf` should be replaced with `path\myFirstAlignment2.pdf` if the pdf file is not in your working directory.

Comment: Only the second solution (2) works for me but the pdf displayed is absolutely tiny. The first solution (img src) does not display anything. Is there any way to control the output size with solution 2?

Comment: @Nova You've probably fixed this long ago, but here's a [possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91442). This also works for including PDFs with multiple pages for PDF output: `\includegraphics[page=2]{myFirstAlignment2.pdf}`

Comment: It is worth noting that if you want to have this .md displayed on the web, the pdf is displayed as desired as an image in Safari but this syntax is not compatible with Firefox or Chrome, unfortunately. These programs do not recognize PDF with the image tag. Instead you would have to use

```<object data="/PATH/TO/images/TITLE.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%"> 
</object> ```

Answer (score 42):

If you are just trying to insert an image that has been exported from, for example, some R analysis into a pdf image, you can also use the standard image options from the knitr engine.

With something like:

````
```{r, out.width="0.3\\linewidth", include=TRUE, fig.align="center", fig.cap=c("your caption"), echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("./images/imagename.pdf")
```
````

Unfortunately you can't specify the initial dimensions of your image output (fig.width and fig.height), which you would need to pre-define in your initial output, but you can specify the ultimate size of the image in your document (out.width). As noted below, however, this is limited to scaling down.

You could also of course leave out the initial directory specification if your files are in the same working directory. Just be aware of operating system differences in specifying the path to the image.

An alternative method is to use Markdown syntax noted by @hermestrismegistus on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown):

```
![Image Title](./path/to/image.pdf){width=65%}
```

This can also be collected for multiple images side-by side:

```
![Image Title](./path/to/image.pdf){width=33%}![Image2 Title](./path/to/image2.pdf){width=33%}![Image3 Title](./path/to/image3.pdf){width=33%}
```

**Edit:**

After working more extensively with in-text referencing, I have found that using r chunks and the `include_graphics` option to be most useful. Also because of the flexibility in terms of image alignment (justification).

As an example:

````
```{r image-ref-for-in-text, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.cap='Some cool caption', out.width='0.75\\linewidth', fig.pos='H'}
knitr::include_graphics("./folder/folder/plot_file_name.pdf")
```
````

The reference can later be used in-text, for example, Figure `\@ref(fig:image-ref-for-in-text)` illustrates blah blah.

Some important things to note using this format:

1. You can only expand PDF images via a code chunk up to the `out.width` and `out.height` conditions set in the original `.pdf` file. So I would recommend setting them slightly on the larger side in your original image (just note that any chart text will scale accordingly).
2. The in-text reference code (in this case `image-ref-for-in-text`) CANNOT contain any underscores (`_`) but can contain dashes (`-`). You will know if you get this wrong by an error message stating `! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.`
3. To stop your plots drifting to the wrong sections of your document, but in a way that unfortunately will generate some white space, the above example includes `fig.pos='H'`. Where H refers to "hold" position. The same can be achieved for the former Markdown option by placing a full-stop (period `.`) immediately after the last curly bracket.

Example:

```
![Image Title](./path/to/image.pdf){width=75%}.
```

Unfortunately, this latter option results in some unsightly full-stops. Another reason I prefer the `include_graphics` option.

Comment: Is there any way to upload a scrollable pdf document, not just an image?

Comment: Hi Juliana, I have seen some pdf viewer options for including plug-ins in html, but haven't worked with them myself.

Answer (score 6):

In relation to the comment of the best answer, there is a way to use the second option, and the output not come out tiny.

Use the following syntax below with the height being a large number. Having text in the brackets is necessary for it to work.

```
![Alt](./file.pdf){width=100% height=400}
```

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers outlined worked well for me in terms of sizing the pdf, so adding another answer using the code chunk options for out.height and out.width to control the size:

```
{r out.height = "460px", out.width='800px', echo=F}
knitr::include_graphics("./images/imagename.pdf")
```