# Problem with pdfpages. Error: Undefined control sequence. 1.222 \includepdf [pages=-]{test.pdf}. Error: LaTeX failed to compile temp.tex

Tags: r-markdown, pdf-generation, tinytex, pdfpages

I'm having problems with using pdfpages package with rmarkdown. I want to insert a multipage PDF into my rmarkdown rendered PDF document. I'm using tinytex.

The yaml has \usepackage{pdfpages}

and in the body of the rmarkdown I have \includepdf[pages=-]{test.pdf}

I keep getting this error:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.222 \includepdf
[pages=-]{test.pdf}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile temp.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See temp.log for more info.
Execution halted

I've gone into cmd and used:

tlmgr install pdfpages

It seems to have said its installed. I see the necessary packages in this location on my PC.
C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\tex\latex

I shutdown R-studio and try knitr to PDF, but same error. If I remove the \includepdf[pages=-]{test.pdf} line then the PDF renders.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting? I've been working on it for a few days now. I could save each page of the multi-page PDF as an image and use includegraph, but that is not as ideal as doing it all at once.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173714/r-markdown-can-i-insert-a-pdf-to-the-r-markdown-file-as-an-image